# pexpectによるSSH多重接続方法について

Tags: python, linux

当方python,linux初心者です。pexpectを利用してsshで多重接続したいのですが、うまくいきません。

実施したい手順は以下の通りです。
1.A端末からB端末へSSH接続
2.B端末からA端末へSSH接続
3.2のSSH接続を切断
4.1のSSH接続を切断

A端末(mac python3.5.1 pexpect4.2.1)
B端末(ubuntu python3.5.1+ pexpect4.2.1)

以下コードです。
a_method1.py

```
import pexpect
def a_method1():
    p = pexpect.spawn('ssh b_ip_addr')
    p.expect('ssword:*')
    p.sendline('passwd')
    p.sendline('python3 /b_path/b_method.py')
    p.sendline('exit')
    p.interact()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a_method1()
```

b_method.py

```
import pexpect
def b_method():
    p = pexpect.spawn('ssh a_ip_addr')
    p.expect('ssword:*')
    p.sendline(passwd)
    p.sendline('python3 /a_path/a_method2.py')
    p.sendline('exit')
    p.interact()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    b_method()
```

a_method2.py

```
def a_method2():
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a_method2()
```

結果は以下の通りです。

```
$ python3 a_method.py

python3 /b_path/b_method.py
exit
python3 /b_path/b_method.py
exit
Welcome to Ubuntu情報

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

999 packages can be updated.
999 updates are security updates.

Last login: from a_ip_addr
B端末:~$ python3 /b_path/b_method.py
B端末:~$ exit
ログアウト
Connection to b_ip_addr closed.
A端末:~a_user$
```

以上です、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

当てずっぽうですが、ログインプロンプトを待たずに `p.sendline` でコマンドを送信してるからではないでしょうか。`p.sendline`の前にプロンプトを待つ `p.expect` 文を追加してみてください。

例： ※Expectのパターンは環境にあわせて変えてください。

```
import pexpect
def a_method1():
    p = pexpect.spawn('ssh b_ip_addr')
    p.expect('ssword:*')
    p.sendline('passwd')
    p.expect('$')               <-プロンプトを待つ
    p.sendline('python3 /b_path/b_method.py')
    p.expect('$')               <-プロンプトを待つ
    p.sendline('exit')
    p.interact()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a_method1()
```